# h2 element won't stay centered unless it is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, centering

This seems like it should be a very simple issue to me, although I just can't figure it out on my own. I have a `h2` element that I want to keep at 85%, and it contains a short line of text. I want it to be centered in its containing `div`, not just for the text to be centered in the `h2` element.
Here's some code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="secondary">
      <h2>Three words of text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main{
  text-align:center
}
div.secondary{
  text-align:center
}
h2{
  text-align:center
  width:85%
}
```

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wF57b/), too

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

To the h2 style rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/wF57b/1/

Comment: Then you can reset the width of the `h2` to auto. Unless of course you wanted an explicit width of 85%;

Comment: In fact I do want that width, primarily for the border (that I didn't bother putting into the fiddle). Thanks a bunch! I've actual used `margin:auto` a number of times previously, but I couldn't recall how to do it for the life of me...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are missing the semicolons in your properties. That makes css parsers skip parsing the rest of the properties.

On the other hand, there are several ways to do this, but as you have already a fixed width, try this:

```
h2 {
  text-align:center;
  width:85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that :( Looks like they've changed their minds though.

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align` property centers the text inside the container (in this case, `h2`).

You don't want to align the text itself, but the `h2` container. So, instead of using `text-align: center;`, you should use `margin: auto`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wF57b/2/)'s your updated jsFiddle.